# pythonic way to replace values in an array over a limit with neighbour's value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm replacing values in an array above a limit like so:

```
ys[ys > zmax] = zmin
```

But now instead of replacing values that are larger than zmax with zmin, I want to replace them with the value of the neighbour in the array that is preceding them: if ys[30] is > zmax, I want to assign the previous value:

```
ys[30] = ys[29]
```

But since the pythonic way doesn't deal with simple things like indices, I have no clue how to do that. Anyone?

Comment: What result do you need when you have a few ys>zmax in a row?  Do you want to use the previous value even if it's >zmax, or do you want to propagate a lower value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're asking for:

```
>>> l = [5, 10, 25, 33, 6, 8, 19]
>>> zmax = 15
>>> [l[idx-1] if (ent > zmax) and (idx > 0) else ent for idx, ent in enumerate(l)]
[5, 10, 10, 25, 6, 8, 8]
```

We just use `enumerate` to get both the index and value for each item in the `list`, and if the value is greater than `zmax`, replace it with `l[index-1]`, otherwise we just take the original value. I'm not sure how you want the case where `l[0] > zmax` to be handled, so I'm just not replacing it at all for now.

Here's the same logic as a normal for loop, just for clarify:

new_l = []
for idx, ent in enumerate(l):
   if (ent > zmax) and (idx > 0):
      cnt = idx -1
      while l[cnt] > zmax:
          cnt -=1
      new_l.append(l[cnt])
   else:
      new_l.append(ent)

**Edit**

Here's a simple way to attempt to make sure **none** of the values in the new list are higher than `zmax`, by trying to swap with the closest, smaller index in the list that contains a value less than `zmax`. Again, if no lower index has a value smaller than `zmax`, we do nothing.

```
new_l = []
for idx, ent in enumerate(l):
   if (ent > zmax) and (idx > 0):
      cnt = idx - 1
      while l[cnt] > zmax and cnt > 0:
          cnt -= 1
      new_val = l[cnt] if l[cnt] <= zmax else l[idx] # If we didn't find a good index to swap with, keep the original
      new_l.append(new_val)
   else:
      new_l.append(ent)
```

Comment: I don't think this will handle contiguous higher values (you have 25 in your output, for example.)

Comment: @DSM that's a good point, though I the OP never actually specified that he needed that. Odds are he probably does want that behavior, though!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, how about this:

```
>>> ys = np.array([10,15,20,30,14,20,30,15,20])
>>> zmax = 15
>>> ys
array([10, 15, 20, 30, 14, 20, 30, 15, 20])
>>> ys[np.maximum.accumulate(np.arange(len(ys)) * (ys <= zmax))]
array([10, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15])
```

---

This produces a forward fill by taking the indices we'd ordinarily use:

```
>>> np.arange(len(ys))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Finding the ones we want to keep:

```
>>> ys <= zmax
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Zeroing the indices that we *don't* want to keep:

```
>>> np.arange(len(ys)) * (ys <= zmax)
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0])
```

and then taking the cumulative maximum:

```
>>> np.maximum.accumulate(np.arange(len(ys)) * (ys <= zmax))
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is in pure python assuming that your first index is less than the max.  If you don't want to use numpy - although numpy is probably very fast

```
ys = [int(uniform(1, 10)) for i in range(20)]
print ys, "before"

maxVal = 5 #set max
for i in range(1, len(ys)):
    if ys[i] > maxVal:
        ys[i] = ys[i-1]

print ys, "after"
```

**output**

```
[3, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 7, 3, 4, 9, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6] before
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3] after
```